# Remove "../" from text file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file containing text such as this

```
../path-to-image/folder1/image.jpg path-to-another-image/folder2/image.png
```

I would like to remove the "../" part and obtain

```
path-to-image/folder1/image.jpg path-to-another-image/folder2/image.png
```

I have tried using sed with

```
sed -i 's#../##g' file.txt
```

But I obtain the following:

```
path-to-imafoldeimage.jpg path-to-another-imafoldeimage.png
```

All the slashes and some other characters were removed and thus the path to my images was broken.

I looked up how to make it match exactly the string using

```
\<\>
sed 's#\<../\>#%%#g' file.txt
```

But the output is identical to input. Is there a way to remove "../" using sed? I need this from command line since I have about 10 files with similar path structures which I will copy into a bunch of directories. Meaning I *can't* do this manually.

Comment: have you tried `'s/\.\.\///g'`?

Comment: Thank you. Indeed that seems to have worked. Could you explain the command?

Comment: @EmilioBotero, `.` in a regex means the same thing as `?` in glob -- it matches any character at all. `[.]` or `\.` both refer *only* to the literal character `.`

Comment: ...I strongly suggest using `[.]`, as it avoids getting into messy situations where you need to double-escape things or figure out which layer of parsing a backslash is intended to apply to.

Comment: To add to 17slims comment, if you intending to only remove the `../` from the beginning of the line use `sed -e's/^\.\.\///g'`

Comment: BTW, `sed -i` behaves incompatibly between GNU and BSD systems -- the usage given here is GNU-only. If you need to write portable code, I'd suggest avoiding it.

Comment: @RedCricket Actually my text file contains about 5000 lines with an identical structure.

Comment: BTW, as a rule, delimiting filenames with spaces and newlines is not good practice, as both spaces and newlines are allowed to exist in filenames. If you were designing your file format from the ground up, you'd be better advised to use NULs instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can't help it in this case. I'm working with a library that requires paths to images to be specified in this way (*Caffe*). I'm not exactly happy about it either, but thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

`.`s have special meaning in regex syntax, and need to be escaped.

Either `[.]` (creating a character class of size one) or `\.` will suffice; I strongly advise the former, as it works properly in a wider array of quoting contexts. Thus:

```
sed -i 's#[.][.]/##g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Dots are special characters in regex. They mean any character (except a newline). So you need to escape them with backslashes in the sed command:

```
sed -i 's#\.\./##g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `sed -i 's/\.\.\///g' file.txt`

`'s/\.\.\///g'` replaces `../` with an empty string, as of the syntax `'s/string/replacement/g'`

`\.\.\/` escapes the dots and the slash, which is necessary because dots and slashes are special characters in regex. After escaping `\.\.\/`, the string reads  `../`.

The following two slashes surround the `replacement` string, which is empty in this case.

**Edit**:
For easier legibility (and to avoid escaping the slash):
`sed -i 's#\.\.\/##g' file.txt`. This is much closer to your initial attempt, and as a revised explanation, `\.\./` translates to `../`, as the slash no longer needs to be escaped. The dots are still special characters and must be escaped with the backslash.

Comment: Any particular reason to use `/` as the sigil, and thus require the literal `/` in the string to need to be escaped?

Comment: I have never used anything but a `/`, but I can see the benefit to using `#` in this case. I will update my answer.